# Database tables / fields you always use in your killer apps

Tags: database-design, web-applications

I'm hoping to tap into some collective experience here, so **What (if any) utility tables, or common fields do you always include in your database design?**

An example is that I always include an `App_Errors` table to store any uncaught exception information in, and an `App_Audit` table which stores all the edit information.

I've mooted (in my own mind) the benefit of including `RecordCreatedDate` and `RecordLastEditedDate` on each data table but not come to any conclusion as to whether or not the information really will be that useful.

To give the question a bit more direction - My current focus is globally accessible web application ( think social networking ).

Ta!

Answer (score 9):

1 A table that contains a version number, so the app can easily check the version of the schema.

2 A table to hold arbitrary variable/value pairs, like a configuration file, but in the database.   (You can put the version number in here....)

Comment: +1 for point 2. I tend to call it "properties". Point 1 is valid too.

Comment: I would add that the arbitrary var/val table works even better as a category/var/val table.

Comment: I have a table called "schema_version".  Each database upgrade does an insert into this table including the version number, description and system date.

Answer (score 6):

I have often used an **audit log table** to keep track of what data has been changed and by whom.

You'd be amazed at how regularly it has been of huge benefit.

Something else that comes up in almost every data model I work on is a variation on a **status table**, generally relating to the status lifecycle of the primary entity.

Comment: what do you actually put in the audit log? App-generated comments, SQL queries, or what?

Comment: @Draemon - for most of the systems I've worked on, a simple record of who changed a record when has sufficed - other have required that the data as it was before change was recorded, and others have required the core SQL statement involved to be recorded.

Answer (score 2):

Every table, regardless of what it does, always starts with an "ID" field, int.

I also save an Errors table, which includes ID, datetime, failed method and overload, and a stack trace if available.

Sometimes I have a settings/stats table, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

For reporting, a numbers table (integers from 0 to 1Mil) and a table of static dates (30 years worth of days).

Comment: I'll echo the above question, why the numbers table? Also what purpose does the static dates table provide - given that most programming languages and reporting systems provide many date functions...

Comment: One use: for reporting gaps - e.g. "list the dates in the last 100 days where no orders were received".

Comment: @Tony - Exactly what I have needed them for. Having the numbers/dates table allows for set based retrieval and avoids cursors or repeating query logic in the app layer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sq

Answer (score 0):

An error message table that has error code, technical message, user message, severity and memo columns. The severity and user message are used to build the message dialog when an error occurs. The error code  and technical message are included in the error log (along with IP of client, date, time, etc) when logging the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to always have a table listing all the users that can access the system.  I prefer this over creating a separate database user for everyone for connection pooling reasons.

Then there is generally a table listing the roles people can have in the system.  A join table indicates who is allowed to do what.  This setup is generally becomes more complicated with application-specific rules things in the business domain.

An audit table is a very good idea.  I include a human-readable column so that non-technical people have a chance to figure out what's going on, as well as storing various keys and important values.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's alway handy to include the following fields:

- Inactive (or Visible/Discontinued/etc)
- InactiveReason

Just makes it really easy to 'soft delete' items so data integrity is maintained and you don't lose that valuable historical info.

And +1 for the Audit Log table that Galwegian mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A membership table. Priceless.

Answer (score 0):

Any table holding user data (as opposed to your system data) has a creation date and last updated date. If there is a 1% chance you might need to know when something happened. This will save a lot of headaches in the future. While I don't like triggers, using them to maintain these two fields is worth it. If you use real database logins, then created_user and updated_user are useful too.