# How do I select dates between two given dates in an Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I select dates between two given dates in an Oracle query?

Comment: See also [Generate a range of dates using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sql)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_DATE('12/01/2003', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - 1 + rownum AS d
FROM all_objects
WHERE TO_DATE('12/01/2003', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - 1 + rownum <= TO_DATE('12/05/2003', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

from

http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/select-all-dates-between-two-dates-92997.html

Comment: -1 This code example (from the linked page) is answering a slightly different question, and is more complicated than needed for the question asked here.

Comment: @payne, Greg has given the best answer so far. All others *assume* that there is a table involved. Granted, that's possibly what the OP *wanted* (as opposed to *did*) ask, but then again, if someone is too lazy to state exactly what he wants, he should get what he asked for. Therefore +1

Comment: I guess with the slightly vague requirement it wasn't clear that the OP wanted to select from a table - I guess we'll find out if and when an answer is accepted.

Comment: Anything based on a table is predicated on the notion that your date range will be less than the number of rows in the table. If you happen to pass in a big date range this solution fails. Which is why using the LEVEL pseudocolumn like my solution is preferable as it is valid for any arbitrarty range.

Comment: suppose if i need to take startdate as sysdate(current date) instead of specific date what can i do?

Comment: Just replace the to_date('12/01/2003', 'MM/DD/YYYY') entries with current_timestamp

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_date_field BETWEEN DATE '2010-01-01' AND DATE '2011-01-01';
```

Comment: Who said anything about Jan 1st 2010 to Jan 1st 2011, I just aswell might ask. What is the difference??? sysdate is a date just as Jan 1st 2010

Comment: well because sysdate is slightly different to a usual date, and without explaination of what sysdate does - it would make more sense to stick with a traditional date. Nothing wrong with SysDate - but it needs a bit more explanation that you provided.

Comment: @Ronnis - rather than just down voting how about you answer the question and supply an alternative?

Comment: @Andy Paton, I'd rather upvote yours if you used to_Date or DATE literals.

Comment: ok you two, stop fighting or I'll take your toys away... and downvote you both.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the LEVEL pseudocolumn in a tricky way to generate a series, so, for example, to get the list of days between today and 20 days from now I can:

```
select trunc(sysdate+lvl) from
  (select level lvl from dual connect by level < ((sysdate+20)-sysdate - 1) )
order by 1
```

Generically you can see how this would apply for any two given dates.

```
select trunc(early_date+lvl) from
  (select level lvl from dual connect by level < (later_Date-early_date-1) )
order by 1
```

And you can adjust the clauses if you want to include the two end dates as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the below to get a list of calendar dates between a date range (similar to Michael Broughton's solution)

```
select (trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(sysdate) - (to_date('start_date')))) -1 + level  from dual
connect by level <= 
((select (trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(sysdate) - (to_date('end_date'))))-
(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(sysdate) - (to_date('start_date'))))from dual)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this so often for a scheduling app I work on that I created a pipelined table function.  Sometimes I need days, hours or 15 minutes between times.  This is not exactly my function, because my code is in a package.  For example, here, I'm getting days between Jan 1 2020 and Jan 10 2020:

```
SELECT
    days.date_time
FROM
    table(between_times(TO_DATE('2020-01-01'),TO_DATE('2020-01-10'),(60*24), 'Y')) days
```

The pipelined function:

```
function between_times(i_start_time TIMESTAMP, i_end_time TIMESTAMP, i_interval_in_minutes NUMBER, include_end_time VARCHAR2 := 'N')
  RETURN DateTableType  PIPELINED
  AS
    time_counter TIMESTAMP := i_start_time;
  BEGIN
    IF i_start_time IS NULL OR i_end_time IS NULL or i_start_time > i_end_time OR i_interval_in_minutes IS NULL OR
      i_interval_in_minutes <= 0 THEN
        RETURN;
      END IF;
      LOOP

        -- by default does not include end time
        if (include_end_time = 'Y') THEN
          exit when time_counter > i_end_time;
        ELSE
          exit when time_counter >= i_end_time;
        END IF;
        
        
        pipe row(DateType( time_counter ));     
        time_counter := time_counter + i_interval_in_minutes/(60*24);
        
      END LOOP;
      
      EXCEPTION  WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN NULL;      
  END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "between".  In a general sense:

```
select * from someTable where dateCol between date1 and date2;
```

note that dateCol is defined as a date and date1 and date2 are also date values.  If these aren't dates, then you'll convert them to dates using to_date function.

Answer (score -1):

with all_days as (select trunc(to_date('12-03-2017','dd-mm-yyyy')+levl)-1  as all_dates from
  (select level levl from dual connect by level < (sysdate-to_date('12-03-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')+1) )
order by 1)
select count(*) as no_of_days from all_days where ltrim(rtrim(to_char(all_dates,'DAY'))) not in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY');

Comment: this query doesn't generate a list of dates.