# Continuous dates in Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-8, cognos-determinants

I need some suggestion to generate a continuous dates in between a specified selected date range in Cognos. I can create a separate Data item for this but I don't know what to do after that. Looking for a quick help

Comment: can you provide an example of how you want the data to look like?

Comment: If I am selecting a date range from jan1st to Jan 31st I need a continuous dates without any date missing in between like jan1st 2018 Jan 2nd 2018  and sO on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your list from a Calendar table which joins to your query in framework, or create a seperate Query Subject that pulls in the date list from a Calendar table or custom SQL. For more info on generating a range of dates using SQL see this: [Generate a range of dates using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sql)

Once you have a query subject with a date field that contains 1 record per date you want, create a dummy field to use to join it to your main query.  A simple data item named 'join1' with the value '1' will work.  Create the same field in your main query.  Join the two Query Subjects together on the 'join1' field.  This is going to result in your data getting multiplied out into the date range.  IE. If you have a main query that lists 1 record per employee, the result after the join will be 1 record per employee per date in your date range.