# Generate a range of records depending on from-to dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I have a table of records like this:

| Item | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018-01-03 | 2018-03-16 |
| B | 2021-05-25 | 2021-11-10 |

The output of select should look like:

| Item | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 2018 |
| A | 02 | 2018 |
| A | 03 | 2018 |
| B | 05 | 2021 |
| B | 06 | 2021 |
| B | 07 | 2021 |
| B | 08 | 2021 |

Also the range should not exceed the current month. In example above we are asuming current day is 2021-08-01.

I am trying to do something similar to [THIS with CONNECT BY LEVEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sql) but as soon as I also select my table next to dual and try to order the records the selection never completes. I also have to join few other tables to the selection but I don't think that would make a difference.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row generator it is, but not as you did it; most probably you're missing lines #11 - 16 in my query (or their alternative).

```
SQL> with test (item, date_from, date_to) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 'A', date '2018-01-03', date '2018-03-16' from dual union all
  4     select 'B', date '2021-05-25', date '2021-11-10' from dual
  5    )
  6  -- query that returns desired result
  7  select item,
  8         extract(month from (add_months(date_from, column_value - 1))) month,
  9         extract(year  from (add_months(date_from, column_value - 1))) year
 10  from test cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset
 12      (select level
 13       from dual
 14       connect by level <=
 15         months_between(trunc(least(sysdate, date_to), 'mm'), trunc(date_from, 'mm')) + 1
 16      ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 17  order by item, year, month;

ITEM       MONTH       YEAR
----- ---------- ----------
A              1       2018
A              2       2018
A              3       2018
B              5       2021
B              6       2021
B              7       2021
B              8       2021

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: In Oracle 12c and above there's a lateral join, which allows correlated datasource without additional wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Recursive CTEs are the standard SQL approach to this type of problem.  In Oracle, this looks like:

```
with cte(item, fromd, tod) as (
      select item, fromd, tod
      from t
      union all
      select item, add_months(fromd, 1), tod
      from cte
      where add_months(fromd, 1) < last_day(tod)
     )
select item, extract(year from fromd) as year, extract(month from fromd) as month
from cte
order by item, fromd;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b115f9c3ab94b83379394c45160a0b9) is a db<>fiddle.