# generating range of dates table with rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to create a report on a client level which will take information like start_date and end_date from clients table where client_id is specified. After that the idea is to generate table of dates that can warry in range, depending on the clients start_date and end_date.

My question: Is it possible to create table with range of dates in the moment of query execution (dynamically)?

Or: Can you make sequence of numbers like you would do with for loop without previously defining temp table or assistant procedure?

For example (oracle SQL):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  1   A
            FROM    DUAL    )   A

LEFT JOIN    (  SELECT  10  B
                FROM    DUAL    )   B ON B.B = A.A + ROWNUM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [*recursive CTE*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) for this purpose.

You only need to pass the *start* date and the *stop* date in the *anchor* select of the
recursive CTE

*Example*

```
with cal (dt, stop) as (
select date'2022-01-01', date'2022-01-05' from dual
union all
select dt+1, stop from cal
where dt< stop)
select dt from cal;

DT                 
-------------------
01.01.2022 00:00:00
02.01.2022 00:00:00
03.01.2022 00:00:00
04.01.2022 00:00:00
05.01.2022 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `connect by level` syntax:

```sql
SELECT     TO_DATE('01/02/03', 'DD/MM/RR') + LEVEL - 1 -- Some arbitrary start date
FROM       dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 -- Arbitrarily produce 10 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an *ordinary* hierarchical query to me.

```
SQL> with cal (dt, stop) as
  2    (select date'2022-01-01', date'2022-01-05' from dual)
  3  select dt + level - 1 datum
  4  from cal
  5  connect by level <= stop - dt + 1;

DATUM
----------
01.01.2022
02.01.2022
03.01.2022
04.01.2022
05.01.2022

SQL>
```