# Value for missing data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Question for the SQL gurus. I have a table with 3 columns. [Date, Meter, Quality], where there will only be one line per date for each meter. As an example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyDB WHERE Meter = 'MeterX' AND Date > '1-AUG-2022' AND Date <= '5-AUG-2022' ORDER BY Date;
```

I would query much larger date ranges so would usually miss if there is a date missing. Is there a way that I can have a value returned in the Quality column like "Missing" if that partiqular day is missing from the database? This means that I also need the missing date in the Date column. I also only have read access, so no creating temp tables to join with.

Thank you.

Comment: and your question is...

Comment: In WHERE clause use BETWEEN operator between dates

Comment: What DBMS you are using? It would be more clear if you post a sample of input and expected output.

Comment: you can create the calendar table and perform a join to it

Comment: @Sergey, I should have mentioned that I only have read access to this database, so no creating temp tables. I'll add it to my question now.

Comment: The solution you are looking for is easy possible to do in code. Is there a reason why this needs to be done in SQL?

Comment: Please specify database you use

Comment: Do you want every day in the date range or every day for which at least one meter entry exists?

Comment: @Sergey&@Ahmed - I'm using an Oracle DB, but only have access to the WebSQLEditor.
@Jbadminton - I would if it was possible, no way to connect to the DB with python for example. All they gave us access to is a webSQLEditor.

Comment: On a side note, never do this: `AND Date > '1-AUG-2022'`. `'1-AUG-2022'` is a string. If `Date`is also a string (which should not be the case), you'll get completely unexpected results. If `Date` is a date (as it should be) or a timestamp, then the query may work or fail with a runtime error, depending on session settings. Use date literals instead: `AND "Date" > DATE '2022-08-01'`.

Comment: The typical SQL solutions: For e"very day in the date range" use a recursive query to generate the dates, then outer join your data. For "every day for which at least one meter entry exists": Cross join distinct dates with distinct meters, then outer join your data.

Comment: @Thorsten - Thanks for the advice. I need every day in the date range for the meter that I specify in the query. But if the day is missing, it'll just have a gap, which is not what I want.

Comment: Okay, then use a recursive query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to a row-generator:

```sql
SELECT c.day,
       m.meter,
       COALESCE(m.quality, 0) AS quality
FROM   (
         SELECT DATE '2022-08-01' + (LEVEL - 1) AS day
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY DATE '2022-08-01' + (LEVEL - 1) <= DATE '2022-08-05'
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MyDB m
       PARTITION BY (m.meter)
       ON (c.day <= m."DATE" and m."DATE" < c.day + 1)
WHERE  m.Meter = 'MeterX'
ORDER BY c.day;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mydb ("DATE", meter, quality) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-08-01', 'MeterX', 42 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-02', 'MeterX', 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-04', 'MeterX',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-08-05', 'MeterX', 99 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DAY | METER | QUALITY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01-AUG-22 | MeterX | 42 |
> | 02-AUG-22 | MeterX | 23 |
> | 03-AUG-22 | MeterX | 0 |
> | 04-AUG-22 | MeterX | 7 |
> | 05-AUG-22 | MeterX | 99 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e7196e31ba26d682869a7e76a8d7ebe)*

Answer (score 0):

for postgres this could work for you

```
with date_dimension as (
    SELECT dd::DATE
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2022-08-01'::timestamp 
            , '2022-08-05'::timestamp
            , '1 day'::interval) dd
)
select * 
from my_table
left join date_dimension on date_dimension.dd = my_table.Date
where Meter = 'MeterX' 
and Date > '2022-08-01' 
and Date <= '2022-08-05' 
order by Date;
```

Comment: Thanks Dalmas, doesnt seem to be working for Oracle. :(

Comment: then you can generate your dates using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048969/19800108), then left join it with my_table