# How to generate dates between 2 dates in multiple rows in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `create table date_period(dt_from date, dt_to date);` and I want to generate 1 column output with dates between every 2 dates that I have.

I wrote this:

```
select (dt_from - 1 + ROWNUM) 
from date_period 
connect by ROWNUM <= (trunc(dt_to) - trunc(dt_from) + 1)
```

but it doesn't work properly for some reason, it only works when there's only 1 row in the `date_period` table.

What is my mistake? How do I fix this?

For example, if I have 2 rows in my table:

```
13-FEB-2023, 15-FEB-2023
20-JUN-2023, 22-JUN-2023
```

I want to return this:

```
13-FEB-2023
14-FEB-2023
15-FEB-2023
20-JUN-2023
21-JUN-2023
22-JUN-2023
```

But with the query I wrote, I get this:

```
13-FEB-23
14-FEB-23
15-FEB-23
23-JUN-23
```

I was able to achieve this using recursive common table expressions, but how do I do this with connect by?

Comment: I have to agree with @pavel_orekhov "Generate a range of dates using SQL" is a very generic question and so are the answers. Here there is a problem of a query unexpectedly stopping plus a data model constraint that does not exist in the prior question. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418318/generate-a-range-of-dates-using-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the use of `PRIOR dt_from = dt_from` in the query to ensure that the generated dates are treated as rows. Without this the query simply stops at the final actual data row. `AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL` is introduced to avoid creating a Cartesian product.

```
CREATE TABLE date_period(dt_from DATE, dt_to DATE);

INSERT INTO date_period(dt_from, dt_to) VALUES (DATE '2023-02-13', DATE '2023-02-15');
INSERT INTO date_period(dt_from, dt_to) VALUES (DATE '2023-06-20', DATE '2023-06-22');

/*
Using a hierarchical query with the CONNECT BY clause 
to generate the dates between dt_from and dt_to for each row in the table. 
The PRIOR conditions used to prevent the query from generating a Cartesian product.
*/
SELECT dt_from + LEVEL - 1 AS dates
FROM date_period
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= dt_to - dt_from + 1
AND PRIOR dt_from = dt_from
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL;
```

| DATES |
| --- |
| 13-FEB-23 |
| 14-FEB-23 |
| 15-FEB-23 |
| 20-JUN-23 |
| 21-JUN-23 |
| 22-JUN-23 |

A more "modern" and SQL standard compliant approach would be to adopt a "recursive CTE" instead of Oracle's proprietary syntax. e.g.

```
/*
This recursive CTE generates the dates between dt_from and dt_to for each row in the table 
by repeatedly adding one day to dt_from until it is equal to dt_to.
*/
WITH date_range (dt_from, dt_to) AS (
  SELECT dt_from, dt_to FROM date_period
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dt_from + 1, dt_to FROM date_range WHERE dt_from < dt_to
)
SELECT dt_from AS dates FROM date_range ORDER BY dt_from;
```

| DATES |
| --- |
| 13-FEB-23 |
| 14-FEB-23 |
| 15-FEB-23 |
| 20-JUN-23 |
| 21-JUN-23 |
| 22-JUN-23 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GsAg6Q-w)

---

**Cautionary Note**

There is nothing I can see to stop your date ranges from overlapping and consequently the output would repeat dates. So to avoid this you may need to adopt `SELECT DISTINCT` into eiter of the queries above.

[fiddle with duplicates](https://dbfiddle.uk/M25oZym1)